# Place figures at the bottom of a page

Tags: floats, positioning, lyx

Does anyone know how to place figures at the bottom of a page ?
At the moment, it automatically goes at the top of a new page...

I am using LyX.

Comment: Hi @EdgarHemery and [welcome to TeX.sx](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436). In its current form, your question might not receive many answers. Please take a look at the [How to Ask](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/how-to-ask)-page and try to improve your question according to the guidance found there. This may require you to show some effort on your part in terms of attempting a solution. If you have questions about what to do or if you don't quite understand what this means, please ask for clarification using the `add comment` function.

Comment: Isn't the `\begin{figure}[!hbt]` works for this? [More about this](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Floats,_Figures_and_Captions#Figures).

Comment: @m0nhawk `hbt` will not choose bottom as the first option, see http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/39017/how-to-influence-the-position-of-float-environments-like-figure-and-table-in-lat/39020#39020 for an extensive explanation of the LaTeX algorithm. However, this may not help if LyX is used.

Answer (score 7):

You insert the figure following the menus Insert > Float > Figure. Once the figure is placed and the cursor is positions on/in it, follow the menus Edit > Float Settings... Here you can update the float placement:

[image]

This will change the code in the code window to add the float placement specifier for the `[b]`ottom:

```
\begin{figure}[b]

\end{figure}
```